# Отмена события Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Не могу понять, как сделать правильно такое: мне надо, что бы событие, которое повешено на `keyup` срабатывало только после того, как пройдет 2 секунды с последнего нажатия.

Раньше я делал так

```
let timer
  clearTimeout(timer)
  timer = setTimeout(function(){
    axios
    .post(self.$root.apiLink + 'geo/street', {
      q: event.q,
      lang: self.$ml.current,
      place: self.city
    })
    .then(response => (
      this.citiesObject = response.data
    ))
  }, 2000)
```

Создавался таймер и если пользователь вводил дальше, старый убирался, создавался новый и так далее. То есть всегда срабатывал только последний.

Сейчас же, если я введу 5 символов, то через 2 секунды сработает 5 раз событие.

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0):

Отвечу сам на свой вопрос - в vue setTimeout возвращает не id таймера, а объект таймера, из которого надо достать id